# Background color not functioning once object is position: fixed

Tags: html, css, position, background-color, fixed

Creating a fixed marquee block at bottom of screen. However, once object becomes fixed, the background color (#ffffff) dissapears. I've tried adding it to several different places with no luck. What am I missing here?

See the site in action here: 
http://www.rauques.com/

This section is for global (allows fixed item to override wordpress theme).

```
 /* This is what makes our section fixed */
 .fixed-section {
 position: fixed !important;
 left: 0 !important;
 bottom: 0 !important;
 pointer-events: none !important;
 mix-blend-mode: multiply;
 display: block;
 } 

 /* This makes our fixed elements clickable */
 .fixed-section .column-content {
 pointer-events: auto !important;
 }
```

The following is the HTML/CSS for fixed marquee:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>


 .marquee {
 height: 40px;
 width: 100% ;
 display: block;
 background-color: #ffffff !important;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;

 }

 .marquee div {
   display: block;
   width: 200%;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: #ffffff !important;
   position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;
   animation: marquee 8s linear infinite;
   display: block;
  }

 .marquee span {
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
 color: #000000;
 background-color: #ffffff !important;

 }


 hr.style1 {
 display: block;
 margin-top: 0em;
 margin-bottom: 0em;
 }

 hr.style2 {
    display: block;
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 0em;
    }

 @keyframes marquee {
 0% { left: 0; }
 100% { left: -100%; }
 }  



 </style>
 </head>
 <body>




<hr class="style1">
<div class="marquee">
 <div>
   <span><H4>Faire un don &agrave; l'Accueil Bonneau</H4></span>
   <span><H4>Faire un don &agrave; l'Accueil Bonneau</H4></span><br>
 </div>
</div>
<hr class="style2">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the property `mix-blend-mode: multiply;` on the `.fixed-section` class, change it to `normal`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey **Anjela** If I got your issue right, this issue is located a bit above your current markup, on the `section` tag for the fixed element, the property `mix-blend-mode` is what is causing the issue.

You can read more about the property [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#mix-blend-mode) so you can understand better how it works and why it easily to make it conflict with other properties if not applied correctly or if you are not careful to take into account the inheritance of the CSS cascade.

Let me know if this help you, good luck!

[image: Screen capture]